# Vincular seleção entre dois ListViews

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

Seria possível vincular a seleção única entre dois objetos `ListView` via XAML?

Por exemplo, tenho dois `ListView`, o `TopListView` e o `BottomListView`, ambos configurados para seleção simples, ou seja, apenas um item pode ser selecionado. Porém, como são `ListView` independentes, pode-se ter um item selecionado no `TopListView` ao mesmo tempo que existe um selecionado no `BottomListView`.

E eu quero fazer com que eles trabalhem como se fossem um só, ou seja, se um item for selecionado no `TopListView`, o item que está selecionado no `BottomListView` "desselecionado" e visse versa.

Sei como fazer isso via code-behind, manipulando o evento `SelectionChanged` de cada `ListView`. Mas estou buscando saber se é possível fazer isso sem ter que apelar para o code-behind.

Comment: O pior é que nem usando o evento `SelectionChanged` está sendo simples como eu achei que seria.
O problema é que definir a propriedade `SelectedIndex` via código também dispara o evento `SelectionChanged`. Tentei contornar usando a propriedade `FocusState` para que ele só faça a mudança caso o `ListView` não tenha o foco, mas não surtiu efeito.
Segue o [código](http://pastebin.com/i1psDLK1) dos event handlers.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359424/mutually-exclusive-selection-of-two-listviews

Comment: Em WPF é fácil fazer usando um TargetedTriggerAction e Interaction.Triggers. Não sei se é possível usá-los em UWP ou se há algo equivalente. Se achar útil diga que eu coloco uma resposta.

Comment: @ramaral Será bom, pode ajudar pois `UWP` e `WPF` compartilham muitas funcionalidade, acho até que a maioria.

Comment: Então, para que a resposta seja válida, vou acrescentar a tag `WPF` à pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As respostas do Ramaral serviram para que eu recordasse que eu já havia visto algo parecido, ou seja, alguma coisa relacionada a `Triggers` no `UWP`.
Bem, o equivalente ao `TargetedTriggerAction` do `WPF` é um elemento ativo (**Janela Actives**), da categoria **Behavior** chamado [DataTriggerBehavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/DataTriggerBehavior)
Esse componente permite criar uma Trigger que executa uma ação com base em uma condição.
Esse componente não vem disponível por padrão, é necessário instalá-lo via NuGet, cujo nome do pacote é `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed`.
Na data dessa resposta a versão 2.0 apresentou problemas, assim fiz downgrade para a versão 1.1 que funcionou normalmente.
A documentação e exemplos de como usá-lo é está no link que deixei, mas ele é extremamente simples.
Para o meu problema, ficou da seguinte forma.

```
            <ListView x:Name="HamburgerMenuListView1" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">

                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=HamburgerMenuListView1, Mode=OneWay}" ComparisonCondition="GreaterThanOrEqual" Value="0">
                        <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=HamburgerMenuListView2}" PropertyName="SelectedIndex" Value="-1"/>
                    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </ListView>


            <ListView x:Name="HamburgerMenuListView2" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" Margin="0,0,0,20" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">

                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=HamburgerMenuListView2, Mode=OneWay}" ComparisonCondition="GreaterThanOrEqual" Value="0">
                        <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=HamburgerMenuListView1}" PropertyName="SelectedIndex" Value="-1"/>
                    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>


            </ListView>
```

É necessário configurar os namespaces no XAML, no meu caso ficou:

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

Bem, é isso, vamos pra próxima :)

Answer (score 3):

Em WPF uma forma possível é usar um *TargetedTriggerAction* e *Interaction.Triggers*.

Adicione a referência **System.Windows.Interactivity** ao projecto.

Escreva uma classe que herde de *TargetedTriggerAction*:

```
public class RemoveSelectionTargetAction : TargetedTriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    private static bool _canDoAction = true;
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        var selector = TargetObject as Selector;
        if (selector != null)
        {
            if (selector.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
            if (_canDoAction)
            {
                _canDoAction = false;
                selector.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                _canDoAction = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new 
                InvalidOperationException("Esta acção apenas pode ser aplicada a objectos baseados em Selector");
        }
    }
}
```

No *XAML*, onde for utilizá-la, adicione o *namespace* **System.Windows.Interactivity** e o do seu projecto(TesteWpf, neste exemplo).

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TesteWpf"
```

Na declaração da TopListView acrescente:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <local:RemoveSelectionTargetAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=BottomListView}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

e na BottomListView acrescente:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <local:RemoveSelectionTargetAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=TopListView}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**Notas:**

- `selector.SelectedIndex = -1` faz disparar o evento, por isso foi necessário recorrer à flag `_canDoAction` para evitar que que o código seja executado outra vez.
- Apenas funciona com duas ListView.

Answer (score 2):

Uma abordagem que deve funcionar tanto em WPF como em UWP é usar uma *Attached Property*.

Escreva uma classe para gerir e agrupar os *ListView/Selector*:

```
public class GroupManager
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsGroupedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
         "IsGrouped",
         typeof(bool),
         typeof(GroupManager),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsGroupedChanged));

    public static bool GetIsGrouped(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(IsGroupedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsGrouped(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(IsGroupedProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnIsGroupedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selector = d as Selector;
        if (selector == null)
        {
            throw new
                InvalidOperationException("Esta propriedade apenas pode ser aplicada a objectos baseados em Selector");
        }
        var isGrouped = (bool)e.NewValue;
        if (isGrouped)
        {
            Register(selector);
            if (selector.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                UpdateGroupSelection(selector);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Unregister(selector);
        }
    }

    private static void Unregister(Selector selector)
    {
        GroupElements.Remove(selector);
        selector.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private static void Register(Selector selector)
    {
        selector.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
        GroupElements.Add(selector);
    }

    private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateGroupSelection(sender as Selector);
    }

    private static void UpdateGroupSelection(Selector selector)
    {
        foreach (Selector element in GroupElements)
        {
            if (element != selector)
            {
                element.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
                element.SelectedIndex = -1;
                element.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private static readonly ArrayList GroupElements = new ArrayList(2);
}
```

Nesta classe é declarada a DependencyPropreterty `IsGrouped` e registada como *Attached* que, quando atribuída a uma *ListView(Selector)*, indicará se ela deve ser considerada num grupo em que apenas um dos elementos pode ter itens seleccionados.

Exemplo de utilização:

```
....
....
<Grid Margin="0,50,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="TopListView" local:GroupManager.IsGrouped="True"/>
    <ListView x:Name="BottomListView" Grid.Column="1"  local:GroupManager.IsGrouped="True"/>
    <ListView x:Name="AnotherListView" Grid.Column="2"
              local:GroupManager.IsGrouped="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" Grid.Column="3"/>
</Grid>
.....
.....
```

Neste exemplo a `AnotherListView` só participa no grupo quando o `CheckBox` está seleccionado.

Comment: O que está errado na resposta para receber -1?